# PHP HTML won´t load

Tags: php, html

I wrote the following PHP but if I enter my password correct my HTML code won´t show up and just an empty page is shown .

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if ($pass == "password") 
{
?>  
   <html>
   <head>
        <title>ADMINISTRATION</titel>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
        <h3>Reset Database</h3>
        <form action="DB_Reset.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="RESET DATABASE">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
<?      
}
else
{
    function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
    {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
       exit();
    }
    Redirect('/index.php', false);
}
?>
```

I know that this method of working with passwords is not the safest but for the beginning it should work out. The redirection in case of a wrong password is working but not the HTML code as mentioned before.

Comment: have you got display_errors set to on and have you checked your error log?

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST['pass']`? Is your form, where you request to enter the password, really using POST and not maybe GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    if ($pass == "password") 
    {
        /* do your stuff */
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);
    }
}
?>  
<html>
<head>
    <title>ADMINISTRATION</titel>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Reset Database</h3>
    <form action="DB_Reset.php" method="post">
        <input type="password" name="pass" />
        <input type="submit" value="RESET DATABASE">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget the input needs the name pass else it will not work

Comment: Thanks Liam Sorsby. Edited!

Comment: Actually @DishaV, reading over the code again. I'm not sure the above will work. The OP is only displaying the button if the POST variable has been passed through and the pass matches whereas above, the code is displayed regardless unless a POST request is made. If a simple GET request is made with no POST request then the form will automatically be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['pass']) && ($_POST['pass'] == "password")) 
{
?>  
<html>
<head>
    <title>ADMINISTRATION</titel>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Reset Database</h3>
    <form action="DB_Reset.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="RESET DATABASE">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php      
}
else
{
    function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
{
    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $permanent ? 301 : 302);

    exit();
}
Redirect('/index.php', false);
}
?>
```

Comment: Mind explaining what you did here?

Comment: there is no real difference in the functionality to the code of the OP. The only thing you added is a check, if pass is set in the post data, which would only preserve a notice error (which is, btw. a good change, but will not change the functionality of the code itself :)).